# I would like to have some salad

Tags: word-choice

What are the difference between the following orders

> I would like to have some salad

( I think people do not use it anymore)

> I would like some salad.
>
> I will have some salad.
>
> I will take some salad.
>
> I will get some salad.
>
> Can I have/take/get some salad?
>
> Could I have /take/get some salad?

Comment: "Tone of Humbleness and Politeness" probably!

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh but which one is more polite?That's the point.

Comment: According to me, the very first one is the most polite. But you can't hear people saying that too often now because our generation is moving towards a more ruthless world. Usually people prefer using the second and the third one.

Comment: I know there's been a lot of discussion lately about the trend for asking in restaurants 'Can I get...' rather than 'Can I have...', but 'I will get some salad' _definitely_ sounds as though you are intending to fetch it yourself. You might be, of course, if the restaurant has a salad bar.